# 3 finger swipe gesture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In an iOS app I've seen that swiping with three fingers from top to bottom triggers an action.

I'm trying to do the same but even cross platform.

Since the gesture topic seems to be an ingoing development at Xamarin, I would like to ask if this gesture recognition is already built-in in the current Xamarin.Forms version (and cross-platform), or if I have to use a third party solution or try to program it myself.

I haven't been able to find a clear statement as the discussions and projects are so widely spread and perhaps not up to date anymore.

Comment: You can create a custom render of the view and add all the gesture that you want, or crate a effect of the gesture and setting to your forms views

Comment: @RicardoRomo Do you have any example or link?

Comment: sorry at this moment I'm out of my home but when I get back, I can create an small sample.

Comment: @RicardoRomo That would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small sample to how to add swipe gesture in Xamarin forms take a look on this. https://github.com/ricardoromo/SwipeGestureEffectXF, if you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also add UWP?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have windows machine.

Comment: Sorry, could you also show me to have track 3 fingers at once?